# Magento2 - Override Template order summary in sales email order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, layout, template

I have the template that is using the following to render order summary

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order
>   area="frontend"}}

it is taking the code from the following template

> /app/design/frontend/Corra/Mytheme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

So I want to override this file with my custom module file and use this one.

I created a module "**Corra_Sales**"

I put the .phtml here

> /app/code/Corra/Sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Also, I created the layout with the file:

> /app/code/Corra/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml

The code inside file is:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" as="default" template="Corra_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, I tried with :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Corra_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I clear cache, remove var folder, rebuild, etc.

But it still not working, someone could tell me what I am doing wrong that always take this file ->?

> /app/design/frontend/Corra/Mytheme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Answer (score 2):

the block referenced by **sales.email.order.renderers.default** is the one to override the template

both layout definitions below should do the work and the first layout definition is now deprecated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers.default">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mbs_EmailSaleOverride::sales_item.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

below is the new notation to take over the block template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers.default">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mbs_EmailSaleOverride::sales_item.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, the emails in Magento are more complex than normal pages and I have today written a plugin that takes over the function getTemplate for the block `\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder` and this is finally successfully overriding the template as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder">
        <plugin name="takeovertemplate" type="Mbs\EmailSaleOverride\Plugin\OrderItemDefaultRenderer" />
    </type>
</config>

<?php
namespace Mbs\EmailSaleOverride\Plugin;

class OrderItemDefaultRenderer
{
    public function testafterGetTemplate()
    {
        return 'Mbs_EmailSaleOverride::sales_item.phtml';
    }
}
```

Comment: why you put the sales_item.phtml if I modified the default.phtml file ?

Comment: default.phtml would work too, it is just the way I named my template indeed

Comment: it does not work. still getting /app/design/frontend/Corra/Mytheme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml file. Also, the file app/code/Corra/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml is

Comment: `code`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers.default">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Corra_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page> `code`

Comment: Also as the official documentation says https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act *action is deprecated*

Comment: apologies, I have forgotten about this issue. I will attempt to sort this out. Many thnaks for pointing this out the deprecation

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers.default" template="Moazzam_CustomSales::email/items/order/default.phtml"  />
</body>
</page>
```